# SQL without using union or union all

Tags: sql, operators

I am trying to write a sql query to get table name and counts of multiple tables under same result columns.

Final Table:

```
table_name   table_count
tbl1           10
tbl2           20
tbl3           40...............
```

My environment do not support union and union all. So I am trying to achieve this

I tried using following query:

```
(select 'tbl_1' as tbl1_name,
count(*) as tbl1_count
from sql_table
where.....)A,
(select 'tbl_2' as tbl2_name,
count(*) as tbl2_count
from sql_table_2
where.....)B.
```

The issue with this approach is it is giving out result in multiple columns.

Comment: What about a table-value constructor?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, can you elaborate?

Comment: It would help if you told us what kind of database platform you're using.

Comment: What's the database? You could create a view... or scalar subqueries.

Comment: Add tags for database and interface tool.